# Font changes for a second when site refreshed

Tags: wordpress, fonts, cufon

I need help about my font issue. When I refresh the site, all text-font starts with similar to Verdana, then change to my correct font Quantico. It seems like buzzling. My wordpress theme is using Cufon-fonts.

Comment: Can you post any code or a link to show us? And I'm not sure what 'buzzling' means.

Comment: I think it is loading late. What is the first running file in js format in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Cufon simply replaces the page fonts after page load, so you'll get two different version of the font. The original css font on initial page load, and then the Cufon font after cufon.replace is run. I don't think there is any way around it. You might try this (https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/FAQ#wiki-faq-5) and check when Cufon is actually being loaded.